# Replacing Space from input with dash symbol using pointers

Tags: c++

I need to replace spaces with "-" (dash symbol) by entering a string using pointers.

The input should look like this:

> The sky is blue

The output :

> The-sky-is-blue

I have problems compiling the coding and to get to work.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char result;

int main()
{
    char string[100], *space;
    {
    printf("Enter a string here: \n"); //Enter a string in command prompt
    gets(string); //scans it and places it into a string
    space = string;
    printf("%s\n", space);
    result = space.Replace(" ", "-");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: You use C# in the title, write code in C++ and tag it as C#, C++ and Java?

Comment: `gets` should not exist. Don't use it.

Comment: It's one way to attract three times as many experts.

Comment: The coding is meant to be in C

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++, `char`s or `char*` don't have member functions. Instead, you'd use `std::replace()` in C++:

```
std::replace(string, string + strlen(string), ' ', '-');
```

Following the comment below: In case you can't use `std::replace()`, here is code which has the same effect:

```
while (*space == ' '? (*space++ = '-'): *space++);
```

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: `string` will decay to a pointer in three places on this one line of code! Just because you don't see them it doesn't mean they are not there...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[100], *space;
    {
    printf("Enter a string here: \n"); //Enter a string in command prompt
    gets(string); //scans it and places it into a string
    space = string;

    while (*space == ' '? (*space = '-'): *space++);
    printf("%s\n", space);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Did what you suggested but It still doesn't work. It does compile though

Comment: I didn't claim you should print `space`! That won't work, of course, as `space` is pointing to the end of the string. Try printing `string`. Also, **do not** use `gets()`! Ever. Use `fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin)` instead.